# OCaml Input types

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am learning OCaml and so far I am having trouble to understand the concepts of types.

For example, if we have this following code:

```
# let func x = x;;
val func : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

From the official website, it tells me that `'a` before the arrow is the unknown input type and `'a` after the arrow is the output.

However, when I try to use function composition:

```
# let composition f x = f(x);;
val composition : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

What `('a -> 'b)` means?
Is `'a` related to `f` and `'b` related to `x`?

Another function composition that made me even more confused is:

```
# let composition2 f x = f(f(x));;
val composition2 : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

I don't really understand why we don't have the `'b` in this case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's not composition, it's _application_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'a -> 'b` is the type of a function that takes one argument of type `'a` and returns a value of type `'b`.

`val composition : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b` means that `composition` is a function of two arguments:

1. the first one is of type `('a -> 'b)`, so a function as above
2. the second one is of type `'a`

So, this function returns something of the same type as the return type of the first argument, `'b`. Indeed, it takes a function and its argument and applies that function to the argument.

---

In the second case, you can work backwards from the inner call. Let's have a look at `f(f(x))`

1. `x` is something of any type `'b`. We have no idea what kind of type this is yet.
2. Since we have `f(x)`, `f` must be a function of type `'b -> 'c`. It's `'b` because we know it takes `x` as input, and `x` is of type `'b`.
3. Thus, the type of `composition2` is `('b -> 'c) -> 'b`
4. Since we have `f(f(x))`, the type of `f`'s argument must be the same as the type of its return value. So, `'b == 'c`. Call that type `'a`.
5. Since `x` is of type `'b`, which is the same as `'a`, `x` must be of type `'a`.
6. Since `f` is of type `'b -> 'c`, where `'b == 'a` and `'c == 'a`, `f` must be of type `'a -> 'a`.
7. Thus, the type of `composition2` is `('a -> 'a) -> 'a`

Comment: Now makes so much sense. Thank you for the clarification!